# Showing 2 sets have equal cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A = \{ 3n+1 \mid n \in \mathbb Z \}$$

$$B = \{ 7m \mid m \in \mathbb Z \}$$

I know I have to find a bijection between them, but do I write out numbers in each set and try to guess a function to get from one set to another?

Comment: $f(x)=3x+1$ sends integers to $A$, and $g(x)=7x$ sends integers to $B$. What would happen if we invert $g$, as in $g^{-1}(x)=x/7$. This would send $B$ back to the integers, and then we can send those integers to $A$ using $f$. So, look at $f(g^{-1}(x))=3x/7+1$.

Comment: @elmer, ay I guess that works as well, nice

Comment: @elmer, f(g−1(x))=3x/7+1, does not satisfy being onto thou. Which sets is f(g−1(x)) meant to be a bijective function between

Comment: It is definitely onto $A$. For every element $3n+1\in A$ there is a solution of $3n+1=f(g^{-1}(x))=3x/7+1$ in $B$. Solving for $x$ you get $x=7n$, which is an element of $B$.

Comment: @elmer, Ar thanks, I was solving for it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** There's an obvious bijection from $\mathbb Z$ onto each of them.

Comment: You mean 3n+1 and 7m ? That would prove both sets have same carnality as Z and that would mean both A and B have same carnality. Is that what you getting at?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.